# finding all html DIV elements that have negative top property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this jquery code should return all DIV's that have negative top property but it doesn't work

```
$('div').filter(function(){return parseInt(($(this).css('top')) <0 )})
```

anybody knows any other solution?

Comment: other alternative is elem.offsetTop(return integet, not necesary use parseInt)

Comment: I may be wrong but arent you trying to call parseInt on a bool?
    $('div').filter(function(){return parseInt($(this).css('top')) < 0; })
Perhaps.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/kgMvk/

Comment: @PNS - nope, that's a condition, saying that **if** the integer parsed from the style "top" is less than zero, return true, otherwise false.

Comment: @PNS: Well spotted. The code inside `parseInt()` in the original code is `($(this).css('top')) <0` which ends up doing parseInt() on the result of the evaluation which is always `0` as `css('top')` returns the value with `px` resulting in `parseInt('##px' < 0)`. Removing the outer `()` fixes it. Very good eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra parens, the parseInt is getting wrapped around your conditional. Try this:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).css('top')) < 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try use `position().top` instead of `css('top')`

```
$('div').filter(function(){return parseInt(($(this).position().top) <0 )})
```

Comment: `css('top')` is fine. Problem is the miss-placed `()`. Which are also still miss-placed in your code and [**your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/feqUc/) also doesn't work until the additional `()` are removed. `$('div').filter(function () { return parseInt($(this).position().top) < 0;})`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return parseInt( getComputedStyle(this, null).top, 10 ) < 0);
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that any `top` style applied through classes seems to be ignored by `this.style.top` but only styles applied directly in-line. See this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvqfm/). Using your code it only picks up 2 out of the 4 divs as 2 have the negative top applied through classes.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - you are of course right, changed it to use what jQuery uses.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
$('div').filter(function(index,element){
    if (parseInt(($(element).css('top'))) < 0) return element;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFgk8/